# What makes SVD special?

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

For a matrix $A\in\mathbb{K}^{m\times n}$ with $\mathrm{rank}(A)=r$ there exist two invertible matrices $S\in\mathbb{K}^{m\times m}$ and $T\in\mathbb{K}^{n\times n}$ such that $$SAT=\left({\begin{array}{ccc|ccc}&&&&\vdots &\\& E_r &&\cdots &0&\cdots \\&&&&\vdots &\\\hline &\vdots &&&\vdots &\\\cdots &0&\cdots &\cdots &0&\cdots \\&\vdots &&&\vdots &\\\end{array}}\right)$$ where $E_r$ is the $r$-dimensional unit matrix.

The SVD guarantuees two unitary matrices $U\in\mathbb{K}^{m\times m}$ and $V\in\mathbb{K}^{n\times n}$ such that $$U^HAV=\left({\begin{array}{ccc|ccc}\sigma _{1}&&&&\vdots &\\&\ddots &&\cdots &0&\cdots \\&&\sigma _{r}&&\vdots &\\\hline &\vdots &&&\vdots &\\\cdots &0&\cdots &\cdots &0&\cdots \\&\vdots &&&\vdots &\\\end{array}}\right)$$

where $\sigma_1\ge \ldots \ge \sigma_r > 0$.

Now why is the SVD so popular, yet nobody speaks of the first transformation. Is it because of the relation of the singular values to the eigenvalues of the matrix $A^HA$?

Comment: SVD is easier to work with, for instance, because unitary/orthogonal matrices are easier to invert.  Also, SVD has a more infromative geometrical interpretation.

Comment: The first transformation does come up, however, in the more compact form given by the [rank-factorization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank_factorization).  Rank-factorizations are commonly used in numerical linear algebra